# Remove ControlWrapper from Dashboard

Tags: google-visualization

I have a Dashboard that has a few different ControlWrapper's which each control a different column in a DataView. I have some checkboxes that allow a user to toggle the columns that are shown in the DataView. The issue is when the DataView columns are updated, using view.setColumns(), dashboard.draw() errors because there is now a ControlWrapper that is referencing a column that no longer exists in the DataView. My thought was that I could call dashboard.bind() and rebind the Dashboard with only the ControlWrappers that map to valid columns, but it does not seem to work.

I am wondering if you cannot call dashboard.bind() after a dashboard has already been drawn, or if there is another way to do this and redraw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no way to unbind what you previously bound, you'll have to build a new Dashboard from scratch.